# Fluid header with left-aligned and right aligned element wrapping and filling full height

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<header>
  <h1>Curriculum Vitae</h1>
  <ul id="profile-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

And the following SASS:

```css
header {
  background-color: white;
}
header h1 {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
header ul#profile-menu {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
header ul#profile-menu li {
  display: inline;
}
```

It renders like this on large screens:

[image]

However, I am trying to make the header fluid, so that the `ul#profile-menu` will wrap to the next line, and the header will grow to accommodate the height of both. However, currently it's wrapping, but not left-aligning and the header is not filling the height.

[image]

I'd love to know if there's a way without media queries and just have it wrap in a fluid way while filling 100% height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/reddMd)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: lightblue;
}
h1 {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Curriculum Vitae</h1>
  <ul id="profile-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - but is there no other solution than using flex as it's not really supported in IE?

Comment: Flexbox is supported by IE10/11/Edge...that's pretty good support

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex says it's supported in IE 10/11 but buggy - will this run into problems there?

Comment: It shouldn't, this is pretty basic.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but final question - is there no solution at all for IE9 as I need to support down to that at a minimum

Comment: IE 9 would probably require a different solution and media queries.